# How to create a permissions table independent of the user permissions in Django?

Tags: django, django-permissions

I want to create a permission table that takes django-users and another table as its foreign key . And then gives permissions to it  . What should be there in models.py ?

The doubt can be put across as two separate questions :

> 1. How to use django-users (user id) as a foreign key in another app called
>      permissions .
> 2. How to use table-id that is generated by django when syncdb is
>      done as the priamry key of

that table (Different app) , to be used as foreign key of this app permissions .

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't use the permissions features in django.contrib.auth?  By using the  `permissions` feature of the `Meta` object and the `Groups` table, you can easily create a matrix of "users in group X may perform action Y".

The more I think about this, the more it seems that your implementation would mirror the Groups/permissions feature without extra benefits.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/ for details.

Comment: See the problem which might happen is this . I give permissions not from the user side but from the file uploaded side . When a user uploads a file he can allow only a certain users to view/modify it . What I think this permissions given by users would allow me to only do it from the users point of view and not the file point of view

Answer (score 0):

Your best best is to create a [User Profile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) - which is a model that can be linked to the User model, where the Profile model contains whatever keys you want. Then you can call [User.get_profile()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_profile), and get a model object, check what keys it has.

Answer (score 0):

For the model, you want to look at the ContentTypes app in .contrib. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) and you can just create a foreign key to the user.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Permission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    table = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    ### the rest of the model.
```

Then in your view or whatever:

```
perm = Permission()
perm.user = request.user
perm.table = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(TableToAddPermissionFor)
perm.save()
```

Comment: Once I have the foreign key which is giving me weird integer values . How do I use the foreign key to refer to the table of which it is a primary key ?